An Australian movie that three women kidnap and sexually assault a man
I'm looking for an australian movie made in between 2000-2010 which three women kidnap and sexually assault a man. It was probaby made in Melbourne, but could be an another city also. 
It starts with a man who's about to be kidnapped talking with a girl on his cell phone, near to a bridge on a river. After that he searches a noise from a dark alley and he passes out by an object. He was white, had long black hair, blue eyes, in his 30s or early 40s, middle sized. 
The next scene is he finds himself in a small room without any window, chained of both his arms and legs on the surface and without any clothes on him. He screams for help but three kidnapper women ignores that. He needs to go to the bathroom but they refuses it. He has to pees on himself. They give him only little water and meal. They sexually assault him by inserting an object to his butt and some other disgusting stuff. 
I couldn't remember the motive of their behaviour. It could be either the ex-girlfriend revenge or rage for opposite sex. And couldn't remember if he survived or not.. 

Please try to come to grips with how punctuation works in written English language. The repairs people made to your questions should already give you an overview of how whitespace works around punctuation and make for a good learning example from which future questions can surely profit.

This is the 2006 Australian drama The Book of Revelation with Greta Scacchi and Anna Torv.

Daniel (Tom Long), a dancer, is drugged and abducted in an alley by three hooded women. They proceed to use him as a sex toy in an abandoned warehouse for about two weeks, before they take him in their car and dump him.
When he is left to return to his normal life, he loses his ability to dance and has problems relating with his environment. To reclaim his identity, he seeks revenge. He does so by hitting on every woman who responds to him hoping his abductors would be among them.

Daniel has longish dark hair and strolls on a bridge before coming to the alley. And after his abduction, he lies on the floor, his hands and feet are chained and he reluctantly wets himself. Here's the trailer:



